# Two StreamBuilder using one stream(); Will it increase the number of reads?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Screens(Scaffold) and I'm thinking to use a single `stream()` in both `StreamBuilder`. My question is will I be charged double reads? Or the read will be equivalent to one read?

Comment: Did you get an answer to the same query since I did not get a clear answer for the same?

Comment: No, unless you created a separate stream function and used it on both StreamBuilders. However, I've discovered that using a single stream on several StreamBuilder can result in an indefinite loading bar for other stream builders. When I was using Api boolean, this happened to me. I recommend broadcast your stream. And It will save you some reads if you don't run the main stream function many times. Hope this helps. @vnaren001

Comment: @RajA I exactly having a problem that you said right now, and I`m stuck I want to reuse stream connection that already running (subscribing) in other stream builder can you answer from my question list

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore clients try to minimize the amount of data they have to read from the server. It depends on your code of course, but in most cases there will be a lot of re-use of data that was already read - so that you won't get charged again.

Some examples:

- If both builders are using the same stream, the data for the second one will come from what was already ready into memory for the first reader. So there will be no charges for the second builder.
- If both builder use their own stream, there typically is also a lot of reuse. If the streams are listening at the same time, the SDK will reuse the data between them where possible.
- And if you have disk caching enabled (which it is by default on iOS and Android), the streams will even share results if they're not active at the same time.

Comment: But when I make a Stream function in a class and bind that stream() to two different StreamBuilders, when I navigate to the other Screen stream() is invoked again. That means a request is being sent which increases the reads. Plus when you assign stream() to a Stream<DocumentSnapshot> myStream; the stream only response to a single streambuilder and both. @Frankvanpuffelen

Comment: You might want to give it a try. The clients try to minimize data retrieval from the server.

Comment: Does it increase the reads and if yes how to minimise it because firestore is costly than I thought ? @Frank van Puffelen