# Is there a way to rebuild only an item of a list within stream builder (flutter)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm using StreamBuilder to get documents of a firestore collection. Each document has many fields which are used in a StatefulWidget named JobWidget. The list (ListView.custom) of JobWidgets is what my StreamBuilder shows.

When there is an update in a single job, complete list gets rebuild. Is there anyway to build just that particular item in the list? Thanks.

Below is the minimal reproduction of my code.

```
class JobsDetailView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0), color: Colors.white),
      child: StreamBuilder<List<JobDetailWithID>>(
        stream: readJobs(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<JobWidget> jobItems = [];
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final jobs = snapshot.data;

            /// Sending jobs to parent widget
            this.jobsCallback.call(jobs!);

            for (var x in jobs) {
              jobItems.add(JobWidget(jobDetailsWithID: x));
            }
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
                // TODO: Show reload/try again button
                child: Text(
              'Could not load data\n ${snapshot.error}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(color: Colors.red),
            ));
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return ListView.custom(
            primary: false,
            childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return KeepAlive(
                    key: ValueKey<JobWidget>(jobItems[index]),
                    data: jobItems[index],
                  );
                },
                childCount: jobItems.length,
                findChildIndexCallback: (Key key) {
                  final ValueKey<JobWidget> valueKey = key as ValueKey<JobWidget>;
                  final JobWidget data = valueKey.value;
                  final idx = jobItems.indexWhere((element) => element == data);
                  if (idx > 0)
                    return jobItems.indexOf(data);
                  else
                    return null;
                }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  static Stream<List<JobDetailWithID>> readJobs() async* {
    var stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('jobs')
        .where("timeline.start_dt",
            isGreaterThan: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 122)))
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => JobDetailWithID.fromMap(doc)).toList());
    await for (final snapshot in stream) {
      yield snapshot;
    }
  }
}

class JobWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final JobDetailWithID jobDetailsWithID;

  JobWidget({Key? key, required this.jobDetailsWithID}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<JobWidget> createState() => _JobWidgetState();
}

class _JobWidgetState extends State<JobWidget> {
  /// Creating a StatefulWidget UI showing job details (900+ lines of code so omitted here)
}
```

Comment: "Is there anyway to build just that particular item in the list?" - no, you have to build all the visible widgets

Comment: Try to use statemanagement libraries to update a single variable or try to wrap the streamBuilder on the desired widget which you wanted to update.

Comment: With num. of fields Stream Builder is handling and complexity of tree structure, the later is kind of not a manageable solution here. Give an example of  state management library please and if any short example available somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Also, If we have different stream builders for different widgets which are getting data from same firestorm collection. Wouldn't it increase the read cost?

Comment: Well, the answer for firestore read cost is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974915/two-streambuilder-using-one-stream-will-it-increase-the-number-of-reads